# Refresh option missing on right click menu when on canvas

Tags: javascript, html

When I right click on a js canvas, the refresh page button is not available, is it possible to get the normal menu to pop up?

[image: microsoft edge right clicked]

Here is an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Drawing Program</title>
  <style>
    #canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

  <script>
    // Get the canvas element
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not missing - 'refresh' was never a standard context menu option of a `canvas` element. Why do you believe it should be?

Comment: I just need to be able to let the user refresh the page for the context I'm using it for and I was wondering if there was a hack to be able to have the option to refresh the page when they right click on a canvas

Comment: Are you listening for events on the canvas element?

Comment: You could add a button to the canvas which refreshes the page. However, I'd argue that any logic which requires the page to be refreshed is indicative of a poor design. If the data in the page is expected to change while the user is viewing it, then update the content dynamically using AJAX/sockets/web workers etc

Comment: its for a project where the canvas will be fullscreen for a creative coding project. sometimes it needs to be refreshed to stop lag and the webpage is run in a program that doesn't have access to the refresh icon or f5 shortcut. I don't want to add a button so it can just be a fullscreen visual thing, should I just overwrite the right click with a custom menu with a refresh button? or is there a simpler way